# Cluster of .NET Web Services on one computer

Tags: .net, web-services, iis, cluster-computing

I am working on a .NET Web Service and I want to run multiple instances of that service on the same computer for them to work as a cluster (high availability cluster although using only one computer) and make them communicate through UDP packages in order to perform high availability operations such leader selection (bully algorithm) and so on. 
How could I launch several instances of the same service on the same computer? Do you know any tutorial or info to start working in that direction?

Comment: What kind of services? WCF or ASMX?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Mmmmh its about ASMX services I thought the solution was valid but I think it goes in another direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of each service installation instance must be unique. You should configure your service so that you can change the service name in configuration.

Have a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/MultipleInstNetWinService.aspx) for instructions.